# How to stop click event from creating more than one element?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a project that creates tabs dynamically. For example, each time the user clicks on the "Email" button, it creates a new "Email" tab (which also includes an 'x' symbol to remove it). I want to prevent click events from creating multiple tabs. However, after the user clicks on a tab's 'x' symbol, I want the user to be able to create it again.

http://jsfiddle.net/v6awanwn/1/

```js
$("#mainTab").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    $(this).tab('show');
  })
  .on("click", "span", function() {
    var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
    $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
  });
$('.gtab').click(function(e) {
  var id = $("#mainTab").children().length + 1;
  var tabId = 'contact_' + id;
  var tabtitle = $(this).find('span').html();
  $('#mainTab').closest('li').before('<li><a href="#contact_' + id + '">New Tab</a> <span> x </span></li>');
  $('<li><a href="#contact_' + id + '">' + tabtitle + '</a> <span> x </span></li>').appendTo('#mainTab');
  $('#tabpanel .tab-content').append('<div style="height:400px;" class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '">' + tabtitle + '</div>');
  $('#mainTab li:nth-child(' + id + ') a').click();
});
```

```css
#mainTab li span {
  position: relative;
  top: -31px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="gtab">
        <a><span title="Email">Email</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="gtab">
        <a><span title="system">system</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tabbable" id="tabpanel">
    <ul id="mainTab" class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So do you want to prevent multiple 'email' or 'system' tabs from being added?

Comment: yours working fine if you want to limit creating tabs by number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two elements with same text, you don't do any things. For implementing it you can use code below in click event:

```
// Get title by text
var tabtitle = $(this).find('span').text();

// Checking for similar element by text
if($("#mainTab li").find('a').text().indexOf(tabtitle) >= 0)
    return;
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/5soec2ro/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you give each tab an id based on its type, you can first check whether any such tabs exist (using `length`). If they don't, *then* you can create your new tab.

```js
$("#mainTab").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  $(this).tab('show');
})
.on("click", "span", function() {
  var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
  $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
  $(this).parent().remove();
  $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
});

$('.gtab').on("click", function(e) {
  var tabTitle = $(this).find('span').html();
  var id = 'contact_' + tabTitle;
  var count = $("#" + id).length;

  if (count === 0) {
    var $newTab = $('<li><a href="#' + id + '">' + tabTitle + '</a> <span> x </span></li>');
    var $newContent = $('<div style="height:400px;" class="tab-pane" id="' + id + '">' + tabTitle + '</div>');

    $('#mainTab').append($newTab);
    $('#tabpanel .tab-content').append($newContent);
    $newTab.find("a").click();
  }
});
```

```css
#mainTab li span {
  position: relative;
  top: -31px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="gtab">
      <a><span title="Email">Email</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="gtab">
      <a><span title="system">System</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tabbable" id="tabpanel">
  <ul id="mainTab" class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#mainTab").on("click", "a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //if (!$(this).hasClass('add-contact')) {
    $(this).tab('show');
    //}
})
    .on("click", "span", function () {
        var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
        $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
    });

$('.gtab').click(function (e) {
    console.log('tset');
    //e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var tabExist = 0;
    var id = $("#mainTab").children().length + 1; //think about it ;);
  var tabId = 'contact_' + id;
    var tabtitle = $(this).find('span').html();
    $("#mainTab li a").each(function(){
      if($(this).html() == tabtitle){
         tabExist =1;
        }
    });
    

if(tabExist == 1){
 e.preventDefault();
}else{
     //$('#mainTab').closest('li').before('<li><a href="#contact_' + id + '">New Tab</a> <span> x </span></li>');
    $('#mainTab').closest('li').before('<li><a href="#contact_' + id + '">New Tab</a> <span> x </span></li>');
    $('<li><a href="#contact_' + id + '">' + tabtitle + '</a> <span> x </span></li>').appendTo('#mainTab');
    $('#tabpanel .tab-content').append('<div style="height:400px;" class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '">' + tabtitle + '</div>');
    //$('#tabpanel .tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '">Contact Form: New Contact ' + id + '</div>');
    $('#mainTab li:nth-child(' + id + ') a').click();

}
});
```

```css
#mainTab li span {
    position: relative;
    top: -31px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li class="gtab">
                <a><span title="Email">Email</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="gtab">
                <a><span title="system">system</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tabbable" id="tabpanel">
        <ul id="mainTab" class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
        </div>
    </div>
   <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="common.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Are you looking for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this is to check whether tab with the `tabtitle` already exists. For this example I would like to change your code a bit. First, I would like to add a new attribute to the tab which your code is creating, `data-tab-title`, with that it will be much easier to fine the tab. Next you need a condition which will check whether the tab exists, `if ($('#tabpanel .tab-content div[data-tab-title="' + tabtitle + '"]').length > 0) return;`. Here is a complete click handler for `.gtab`:

```
$('.gtab').click(function (e) {
    console.log('tset');
    //e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var id = $("#mainTab").children().length + 1; //think about it ;)
    var tabId = 'contact_' + id;
    var tabtitle = $(this).find('span').html();

    if ($('#tabpanel .tab-content div[data-tab-title="' + tabtitle + '"]').length > 0) return;

    //$('#mainTab').closest('li').before('<li><a href="#contact_' + id + '">New Tab</a> <span> x </span></li>');
    $('#mainTab').closest('li').before('<li><a href="#contact_' + id + '">New Tab</a> <span> x </span></li>');
    $('<li><a href="#contact_' + id + '">' + tabtitle + '</a> <span> x </span></li>').appendTo('#mainTab');
    $('#tabpanel .tab-content').append('<div style="height:400px;" class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '" data-tab-title="' + tabtitle + '">' + tabtitle + '</div>');
    //$('#tabpanel .tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '">Contact Form: New Contact ' + id + '</div>');
    $('#mainTab li:nth-child(' + id + ') a').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to do here but I'm guessing that you want to make it so you can only have one of each tab in which case you can just add a `bool` datatype that just stores whether the tab of a certain type is already opened. and just run a simple `if` statement before adding a new tab.